# C: SEGFAULT with realloc on char **

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, realloc

Another one in my series of problems with this code. I have below function which is comparing `arg` with every string in the array of strings `reference` :

```
char compare(char *arg)
{
        int iter=0;
        char retchar='0';

        while(iter < no_of_ref)
        {
        //      printf("arg : %s , reference : %s \n",arg,reference[iter]);
                if((strstr(reference[iter],arg) != NULL) || (strstr(arg,reference[iter]) != NULL))
                {
                        retchar='1';
                        break;
                }
          iter++;
        }
return retchar;
}
```

`reference` is global `char **` , but built up dynamically inside main as below:

```
reference = calloc(CHUNK, sizeof(char *));
```

Then some code, then:

```
                        temp_in[pre_pip+1]='\0';
                        reference[no_of_ref]=malloc(strlen(temp_in) + 1);
                        strcpy(reference[no_of_ref++],temp_in);
                        memset(&temp_in,'\0',sizeof(temp_in));
                        pre_pip = -1;
   printf("INDEX: %d, address : %p , val : %s\n",no_of_ref-1,reference[no_of_ref-1],reference[no_of_ref-1]);      //DEBUG
                }
                /*If allocated buffer is at brim, extend it for CHUNK char *  further*/
                if(no_of_ref == (tr*CHUNK - 2))
                {
                        current_size = tr*CHUNK*sizeof(char *);

                        char *retalloc = realloc(reference,current_size + CHUNK*sizeof(char *));
                                if(retalloc == NULL)
                                        perror("ERROR on realloc");
                                else
                                {
                                        printf("Realloced successfully: %p\n",retalloc);
                                        tr++;
                                }
```

The code running fine for test case where no need to `realloc` arises, i.e. Number of input strings is less than `CHUNK`. In case of `realloc`, I'm getting `SEGFAULT` from function. Below is for one of the run:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  __strstr_sse42 (s1=0x3839393433333230 <Address 0x3839393433333230 out of bounds>, s2=0x6020c0 <cmp> "8956549122")
```

Comment: What is `temp_in`? Because if it's a pointer then the statement `memset(&temp_in,'\0',sizeof(temp_in));` will not do what you expect it to.

Comment: Also, you *do* reassign `reference` to the pointer returned by `realloc`?

Comment: temp_in is an static array char temp_in[20]; 
I am not reassigning reference.  Do you mean after successfull realloc do as  reference=retalloc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `realloc` actually reallocates the memory you pass to it, then that pointer you pass as an argument still points to the *old* memory area. The `realloc` function returns a pointer to the *new* memory, so you have to assign that to e.g. `reference`.

Comment: I tried like this, since reference is a char ** : printf("Realloced successfully: %p\n",retalloc);
                                        retalloc=*reference;
                                        tr++;
but no luck

Comment: @DiwakarSharma The other way around: `reference = (char **) retalloc;` *after* the call to `realloc. (The cast is needed since `retalloc` is a `char*`)

Comment: Now this has cleared SEGFAULT..!! but how does it work I am confused. retalloc will point to the start of newly allocated memory. When we assign that to reference, so reference will loose original position right?

Comment: @DiwakarSharma Yes, but `realloc` allocates new memory (the pointer it returns), copies the old memory (previously pointed to by `reference`), and then *frees* the old memory. You might want to read e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

Comment: you are a saviour as always..! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put parenthesis for expression in `realloc()` as

```
//---------------------------------v -------------------v
char *retalloc = realloc(reference,(current_size + CHUNK)*sizeof(char *));
```

Assume `CHUNK=100` and `current_size=200`, your code will allocate `200+100*8=1000 bytes` while you want `(200+100)*8 = 2400 bytes`

Also, make sure you assign `retalloc` to `reference` variable after reallocation.

Comment: agree with the reassigning part, but I think you are getting the sizing wrong. Whatever be the current size I just want space for CHUNK more char * . so CHUNK*sizeof(char *) bytes  + current size bytes.